# why am i getting this error --> ( IndentationError: unexpected unindent )?

Tags: python-3.x, indentation

edit:this is the whole code https://pastebin.com/Njp9AsP4

this is the code that gives me the error:

```
def save_file_as():
'''Save new file or save existing file with another name'''
filename = sg.popup_get_file('Save As', save_as=True, no_window=True)
try:
    if filename:
        file = pathlib.Path(filepath)
        file.write_text(values.get('_BODY_'))
        filename = filepath.split('/')
        window.TKroot.title(filename[-1] + '- memopad')
        return file
except:
    pass
```

and this is the error:

```
[Running] python -u "d:\python\memopad v1.py"
  File "d:\python\memopad v1.py", line 51
    def save_file_as():
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

i first tried googleing it but could only find people who left out the except: line witch is not my problem.

then i tried removing the try: and except: and to my surprise the error remains.

so its 2AM rn and i decided to make a stackoverflow account to see if anyone here could help.

other info: (im using python3.8.3)(im using windows 10)(im using vscode)(and im a nube to programing)

Comment: Show us the code that preceded that — lines 1-50

Comment: Python cares about how you have code indented.  White space matters.  Where as a lot of other programs just use ( ) or { } to define subroutines.  You probably just have a whole section indented too much (or not enough).  I would suggest taking a quick python intro class, like on code academy to just learn those few basics.  Good luck!

Comment: @sniperd im 99% sure it is all indented correctly i have rewritten it over and over the 1% only comes from the fact the error says "IndentationError"

Comment: Have mixed tabs and spaces in your source file? That will trip you up. Try a global expansion of tabs into spaces....

Comment: You think it's indented correctly. Python thinks it's not. I'm going to go with Python's judgment.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ik thats whats tripping me up tho iv tried as much as i could to fix it but python wont agree

Comment: oh for - "i first tried googleing it but could only find people who left out the except: line witch is not my problem". Look at the previous function. Does it look like it's missing something? An `except`, perhaps?

Comment: As somebody else said, if you are mixing tabs and spaces, that will cause a problem.  Or if you use 4 spaces, and sometimes 2 spaces, that will cause a problem.  The indent problem probably isn't that code you posted, it is probably the section above.  It is an indent problem, not a try/except issue, you'd get a different error.

Comment: Just accept the answer below, make sure to upvote him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is that you didn't close the try statement in the previous code try this now

```
def save_file(file):
    '''Save file instantly if already open; otherwise use `save-as` popup'''
    try:
        if file:
            file.write_text(values.get('_BODY_'))
        else:
            save_file_as()
    except:
        pass  
 
def save_file_as():
    '''Save new file or save existing file with another name'''
    filename = sg.popup_get_file('Save As', save_as=True, no_window=True)
    try:
        if filename:
            file = pathlib.Path(filepath)
            file.write_text(values.get('_BODY_'))
            filename = filepath.split('/')
            window.TKroot.title(filename[-1] + '- memopad')
            return file
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: thanks but after trying it i can say this does not solve he problem

Comment: which line is it showing error 51? please write the code that is written before this code

Comment: the full code id in the pastebin

Comment: I amended the answer check now